# Checkbox with JS and Mobile

Tags: javascript

Hello and thanks in advance for any help
In my store page, I have a checkbox that is checked when user agrees with the terms. When he checks the checkbox, submit button is disabled (false). My problem is that this solution doesn't work on iPhone and other mobile devices.

Here's the code:

```js
function terms() {
  if (document.getElementById("cbTerms").checked)
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
  else
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
}

function cbc() {
  if (document.getElementById("cbc").checked)
    document.getElementById("cbc") = ("הריני מאשר קבלת מבצעים והטבות אל הדואר האלקטרוני מפראיה");
  else
    document.getElementById("cbc").value = ".";
}
```

```html
<input class="btn btn-toranj alt" name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="לרכישה" disabled="true">
<br>
<br>
<input type="checkbox-0" id="cbTerms" name="cbTerms" onclick="terms();" style="width:15px; height:15px;">
<p style="margin-bottom:0px; font-size:14px; display: -webkit-inline-box;">הריני מאשר כי קראתי את <a href="regulations.html" style="color:#E49D1F;">התקנון</a>
</p>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cbc" name="os3" oninput="cbc()" style="width:15px; height:15px;">
<p style="margin-bottom:0px; font-size:14px; display: -webkit-inline-box;">הריני מאשר קבלת מבצעים והטבות אל דואר האלקטרוני</p>
<input type="hidden" value="הטבות ומבצעים" id="on3" name="on3">
```

Answer (score 1):

At first sight your first checkbox is not really a checkbox.

`<input type="checkbox-0" ...`> should be more like: `<input type="checkbox" ...>`

With this change it will work.

P.S.:

Consider using braces for your `if() {} else {}` statements as you will propably run into some logic error if you change something in the future (e.g. add a line of code) and forget to add them.

Answer (score 0):

The change event is preferred over click. And in addition, you'd pass the currently clicked checkbox on the fly as following

```
 <input class="btn btn-toranj alt" name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="לרכישה" disabled="true">
 <br><br>
 <input type="checkbox" id="cbTerms" name="cbTerms"  onchange="terms(this);" style="...">
 <p style="...">הריני מאשר כי קראתי את 
 <a href="regulations.html" style="...">התקנון</a>
 </p>
 <br>      
 <input type="checkbox" id="cbc" name="os3"  onchange="cbc(this)" style="...">
 <p style="...">הריני מאשר קבלת מבצעים והטבות אל דואר האלקטרוני</p>
 <input type="hidden" value="הטבות ומבצעים" id="on3" name="on3">

 <script type="text/javascript">
 function terms(me)
 {
     document.getElementById("submit").disabled = !me.checked;
 }
  function cbc(me){
    var val=document.getElementById("cbc").checked?
        "הריני מאשר קבלת מבצעים והטבות אל הדואר האלקטרוני מפראיה":".";
    document.getElementById("cbc").value = val;
}
 </script>
```

Comment: DKSan The checkbox was <input type="checkbox" ...> the checkbox-0 is some answer that i find over the web for "mobile checkbox". Bellash i replace the code with what you provide and nothing change, it's still work over the web you welcome to check : www.praia.co.il/praiamoro.html but over mobile its not working.